# When a group generated by a normal subgroup and a centralizing element is normal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be its normal subgroup. Assume that $a\in G$ commutes with each element of $H$. Is it true that the group generated by $H$ and $a$ is normal in $G$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ it is known that $C_G(H)$ is also normal in $G$. But it does not imply that $\langle H,a\rangle$ is normal for all $a\in C_G(H)$. Consider $H=1$, the trivial subgroup. Now every element commutes with $H$ and $H$ is normal but every cyclic subgroup is not necessarily normal. The easiest way to construct a nontrivial counter example is this :

Consider $S_3$. Now the subgroup $K=\langle (1,2)\rangle$ is not normal in $S_3$. Take the direct product $\mathbb{Z}_2\times S_3$ and set $H=\mathbb{Z}_2$. Now $(1,2)$ commutes with $H$ however $\langle H,(1,2)\rangle$ is not normal in $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Trying to understand your example. If you don't mind, can you make explicit what do $G, H$ and $a$ from the question correspond to in your example?

Comment: $G=S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, the direct product of $S_3$, the symmetric group on $3$ symbols and $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the cyclic group of order $2$. $H=1\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $a$ is the permutation $(1,2)$.

Comment: Isn't $a$ is supposed to be in $G$?

Comment: Well, it is. It was an abuse of notation. Actually $a=((1,2),0)\in S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.